# CodeBlocks suddenly stops working, wont build a new program

Tags: c, arguments, codeblocks

I have been using codeblocks for about 3 months now it was running just fine. Today I wrote a short program and when I tried to build and run it took about 1 minute for the IDE to respond (usually takes a 5-10 seconds). The program did not open and the error displayed was

"ld.exe  cannot open output file C:users/-----/programname.c invalid argument"

I tried building and running  older successful saved c files  and they worked just fine but I cant even create a simple program such as

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   printf("Hello world.");
   return 0;
}
```

also each time I create a file that fails to build, a new file file is created with the name trz*** *.tmp with random numbers and letters for the *'s. 
My codeblocks is version 12.11 and I haven't changed any settings other than font colour.
Any quick fixes that don't require me to reinstall?

Edit: Forgot to add that I'm using windows 8 64 bit and the first time I got this message, I accidentally clicked save file and not save file as if it matters.

Comment: It looks as if a file (somehow) is either not where you (or the IDE) expects it to be, or the permissions state on the directory location you were working has changed.  Are you on Windows 7 by chance?  trz*** suggests you have a virus.  ***[trz virus](http://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=120979.0)***

Comment: I am on windows 8 64bit machine sorry I forgot to mention that. I am working on my personal laptop so I'm not sure if permission is an issue (wasn't before).

Comment: I just edited my comment above.  Read the last link.  Possible?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I searched the trz viruse and did a boot scan and a full system scan on avast. Avast found some of the trz files to be infected but others were not. The full system scan crashed half way. Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: It is due to avast anti virus.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be a good idea to forgo MS Windows 8 and replace it with Linux Mint 16 (Petra) MATE 64bit edition and then install gcc.so,g++.so,gdb.so,Linux Builder Essentials,xterm and then finally Code::Blocks latest version and then you should be able to get back to programming in C/C++ or install Fortran or Cobol and get productive again.